# Skype like p2p architecture for http/https

Tags: java, http, p2p, skype, nat

Like skype, if I have http/https service running on each home box.

I would like to use them from my phone.According to the userId it should go and get the services on different boxes. What can be the design or architecture of the same.

Is there existing libraries available to use them for such design? Or may be any open source solution?

I would like to know, if there is nothing available in open source. How can we achieve it in java.

Thanks
Vipin

Comment: Do you want skype, p2p or http?

Comment: I have http server running on each home box. Like a home application.

Now, two different home application needs to communicate.  Which are under firewall and router/gateway. The nearest resemblance came to me is skype type architecture. I understand, they are not using http as service. But the high level design would be something same as I want.